# Netcat communication in Java

Tags: java, sockets, unix, nagios, netcat

I am trying to to get a connection from an Java application to a server. I am able to get data from the server by typing in the shell:

```
cat query.txt | nc server port
```

Now, I am trying to do the same in Java. I already tried some third party APIs like jetcat. The server should be also available through a Unix socket, but currently I am not able to get a connection.

The standard Java socket also hasn't worked. When I sent my query, the server never responded.

```java
public class Server {
    private Socket socket;
    
    public Server(String url, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        socket = new Socket(url, port);
    }
    
    void sendMessage(String nachricht) throws IOException {     
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        printWriter.print(nachricht);
        printWriter.flush();
    }
    
    public void read() throws IOException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                    try {         
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        char[] buffer = new char[200];
                        int anzahlZeichen = bufferedReader.read(buffer, 0, 200); // blockiert bis Nachricht empfangen 
                        System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, anzahlZeichen));
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();                 
                  }
             }
        });  
        t.start();}}
```

The system is Check_MK based on Nagios and using LQL (Livestatus Query Language)

Any ideas how to use netcat in Java - or any alternatives to netcat?

Comment: Note:  the Socket constructor's first argument is a hostname or an IP address, not a URL.  If your string named `url` contains, in fact, a URL then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run programs, including netcat, from Java.  See [`Runtime.exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-).

netcat is simply a program that opens a socket, writes to it and reads from it.  You can do that *(open a socket, write to it and read from it)* directly in Java without dealing with pipes and subprocesses.  Add to your question the Java program you wrote using java.io.Socket.  My first guess is you didn't set the [TCP_NODELAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#TCP_NODELAY) flag and/or didn't flush the buffered stream and so the server didn't receive your request.

---

After creating your socket, try setting TCP_NODELAY:
    [`socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay-boolean-)

Use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), or similar, to capture the network traffic and see if your message is actually being sent to the server.

Comment: Can you give me an example how i can directly use netcat without pipes ? As in my example i have to send a query via netcat to my server and read the response from it.

Comment: You can't run other processes without pipes.  You can "open a socket, write to it and read from it" without using pipes (and netcat).

Comment: Alright, with which socket do i need to work ? I tried the standard Java Socket but this didn't work for me. I have added my code in the first post.

Comment: you completely, did not, answer the question. the ability to run a program does not guarantee the program will be available. please consider deleting your answer. For review, the question is Netcat communication in Java, not netcat communication with shell, or system exec.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using http://junixsocket.googlecode.com/ and by directly accessing the UNIX socket on the Server.

Comment: Moved from GoogleCode to: https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket